# Why can't find be used in the view as it is used in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm currently going through Michael Hartl's railstutorial.org, and have run into a question that Google/Stackoverflow don't seem to be answering: The tutorial has us display user information in the view by putting `<%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>` in show.html.erb. In the controller, it has us define a `show` method: `@user = User.find(params[:id])`.

I understand why this works, but what I don't understand is why the following code does not produce the same result (I removed the `show` method from the controller and tried to place all the code in the view). These are my editions to show.html.erb:

`<%= @user.find(params[:id]).name %>, <%= @user.find(params[:id]).email %>`

It returns "undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you understand by now from the other answers and probably the tutorial that you should not have this logic in the view, HOWEVER, to answer your question:

The reason why `<%= @user.find(params[:id]).name %>` generates the error
`undefined method 'find' for nil:NilClass` is because `@user` is an instance variable which you deleted from the `show` method in the controller. So now, `@user` is nil and doesn't exist. Also, when you want to query the database you must use the `class` (model) name which is `User` instead of `@user`.

So whiles its bad practice to do this, if you wanted to, you could do `<%= User.find(params[:id]).name %>` (as long as its a correct id) and that would work. Your params are available in the view as they are in the controller too.

Finally, if you intend to use the show view, you cannot completely delete the show method, you must have at least:

`def show
end`

in order for it to work.

Comment: Great response, thank you. Ya, I understood that it shouldn't be in the view, was just wondering the logic behind why in order to better understand the MVC way.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't have a lot of logic in the views, but I think the code you are looking for is:

```
<%= User.find(params[:id]).name %>, <%= User.find(params[:id]).email %>
```

Answer (score 0):

params is probably not available in the view, and it shouldn't.

Your problem is the main reason why you should do your data preparation in the controller: to catch issues with the data. That's the reason a controller exists.

Your code would make two requests to the database instead of one, if it wouldn't be for rails side query caching.

Prepare your `@user` in the controller and access it in the view. It will make testing and refactoring your code way easier and greatly improve readability.

Compare

```
<%= User.find(params[:id]).name %>, <%= User.find(params[:id]).email %>
```

VS.

```
<%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
```